# Scenario Based Query: Skipping validation for a class without using IF condition

Tags: c#, scenarios

Consider you have the following classes: `Class1`, `Class2` .... `Class1000`. 
All the classes are inheriting interface `IClass`. 
All the classes can be validated using below code

```
Validate(IClass class) 
{

}
```

How can we skip validation for class 200 to class 300 (these numbers can vary, so no logic using numbers) without using if condition?

Comment: You need to show what code decides to call `Validate()` and whether `Validate()` could be moved to the class itself.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, i'd move your validate check into the model.

E.g.

```
public interface IClass{

    bool ShouldValidate();
}
```

Then, in each class:

```
public class Class200
{
  public bool ShouldValidate() => false; // because whatever
}
```

Then in your validate:

```
public void Validate(IClass class)
{
    if(class.ShouldValidate())
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

This way the logic belongs to the `IClass` instances, and anyone willing to extend this knows exactly how to implement the exception.

Also, for classes 200-300, you can inherit them from a common base class that always returns `false` to have a DRY pattern.

**Update** Another option is putting validate inside the class directly, e.g. like so:

```
public interface IClass{

    void Validate();
}
```

Then just leaving the method empty in classes 200-300, e.g.

```
public class Class200
{
  public bool Validate()
  {
  }
}
```

and implement where needed

```
public class Class1
{
  public bool Validate()
  {
   // do awesome things here
  }
}
```

Comment: Got your point. But can we come up with a methodology where if condition is not used in Validate method. ?

Comment: @Venkatesan That depends on what else you do inside your `Validate`.

Comment: @Venkatesan check my update, not sure if that is what you mean.

Comment: Having the class do its own validation seems like the best option to me.

Comment: @Chris that depends on how intense that other logic is, whether the class is used as a DTO/Model that is serializable, and how many dependencies that validation may have. Within the context of OPs question - sure. I would never put validation methods in my api models, though - only attributes.